# css text align issue, same code 2 different servers

Tags: html, css, alignment

So I just moved from the design phase to the developing stage and after splitting up my static code to codeigniter views on a client server I got this weird css but on 1 tiny part of the website.

I have these links part of the "Official NGK Canada Part Finder" section and my text is breaking from the same line on my new server.

Instead of showing code extracts here is the link to both sites:
http://gfortin.com/css_practice/page.html (works fine)
http://www.sparkplugdepot.com/dev/index.php/home (unaligned)

Everything works perfectly from what I can tell so far, can anyone help me find this bug?

Also I did clear the cache to make sure it wasn't the old code still showing up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are floating elements within your `.link-wrap`, you must clear those to make them look the way you want.

```
.link-wrap {
  height: 40px;
  margin: 2px 50px;
  position: relative;
  clear: both;
}
```

As to why, I'm not sure.  However, I'm curious as you may have noted, your navigation is 4px taller on one.  If you look at the computed styles, one is 55px, the other is 51px. What os's are on these servers?